# Homebrew is "cowardly refusing" to install OpenCV

Tags: installation, homebrew, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV with Homebrew.

After typing

```
sudo brew install opencv
```

I get this error message

> Cowardly refusing to sudo brew install

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

**You do not need `sudo` for Homebrew**

Run:

```
brew install opencv
```

Homebrew [never needs elevated privileges](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ) for anything – except for when there are some conflicts with other installed libraries:

> Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo. You can decide to use it but we strongly recommend not to do so. If you have used sudo and run into a bug then it is likely to be the cause.

If you can't install it without `sudo`, make sure you own `/usr/local` and have the correct permissions – also by [running this script](https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518). Running `brew doctor` will also generally give you some good hints.

Comment: If I do that I get: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar

Comment: Did you ever mess around with `chmod`, possibly in combination with `sudo` there? Try `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`. Does it work after that? If not, please post a complete `ls -la` listing of `/usr/local` and what `brew doctor` says.

Comment: Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: Unsatisfied external dependency: numpy
Homebrew does not provide Python dependencies, easy_install does:

    easy_install numpy

Comment: Sorry it didnt work. But to what did you change the user. numpy is installed but i have to run python in 32 bit mode, cause I got 64 bit python installed.

Comment: Ahah, see, we're getting there. For the future, please include things like these in your question, we can't magically guess anything. I don't understand your latest question … please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/391021/edit) your original post and include the `ls -la` of `/usr/local`. Also, maybe think about uninstalling MacPorts or Fink, whatever you have.

Comment: Cellar has the following rights: drwxr-xr-x and wheel is the group. Is that enough info ? What else do you need. Thanks by the way for the help.

Comment: That's probably not enough info. The group should probably be `staff`. But … this is the third time I've asked: **Please post the complete output of `ls -la /usr/local` in your original question.** – I'm glad to help, but you need to help a bit as well!

Answer (score 2):

The install script of opencv wants to link the libraries into `/usr/local/lib`, but that directory needs higher privileges. Even if `brew` refuses to `install` as root, you can just use

```
sudo brew link opencv
```

after you ran `sudo install` as a user. This worked for me.

Comment: as another answer says, you should note that: "Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo. You can decide to use it but we strongly recommend not to do so. If you have used sudo and run into a bug then it is likely to be the cause."

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same issue. A quick fix is to manually create the /usr/local/Cellar folder, then try again without sudo.